# Continuous time law of large numbers for a stationary process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, independence, law-of-large-numbers, stationary-processes

Suppose $\{X(t)\}_{t>0}$ is a continuous time weakly stationary stochastic process, and suppose it has $0$ mean. Then $\gamma(t,h):=\text{Cov}[X(t),X(t+h)]=\mathbb{E}[X(t)X(t+h)]$ as a function is independent of $t$.

I have seen it stated that $$\gamma(h)=\lim_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}X(t^{\prime})X(t^{\prime}+h)dt^{\prime}.$$

I suppose this is a continuous analogue of the law of large numbers, as because of stationarity we have that $X(t^{\prime})X(t^{\prime}+h)$ is identically distributed to $X(t^{\prime\prime})X(t^{\prime\prime}+h)$ for all $t^{\prime}\neq t^{\prime\prime}$. However, in the regular law of large numbers we also have independence, but I don't think it's the case that $X(t^{\prime})X(t^{\prime}+h)$ is independent of $X(t^{\prime\prime})X(t^{\prime\prime}+h)$ for all $t^{\prime} \neq t^{\prime\prime}$?

Can anyone point me to a reference for continuous time laws of large numbers applied to stationary processes?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It looks more like an ergodic theorem, rather than law of large numbers.

Comment: @herbsteinberg it does! i'll do more research on that, thank you for the comment.

Comment: Informally, it follows from the "continuous" ergodic theorem.  The "weak stationarity" assumption will make it harder to find a reference.